# Mongo db sorting on multikey index fields

Tags: mongodb, sorting, indexing

I was going through mongo db indexes and found this when i create index on multi key field and try to sort the result the behavior is strange.
For example:

```
> db.testIndexes.find();  
{ "_id" : ObjectId("584e6ca8d23d3b48f9cb819d"), "type" : "depart", "item" :  "aaa", "ratings" : [ 5, 8, 9 ] }  
{ "_id" : ObjectId("584e6cb2d23d3b48f9cb819e"), "type" : "depart", "item" : "aaa", "ratings" : [ 2, 3, 4 ] }  
{ "_id" : ObjectId("584e6cbdd23d3b48f9cb819f"), "type" : "depart", "item" : "aaa", "ratings" : [ 10, 6, 1 ] }  

db.testIndexes.createIndex({ratings:1});
```

Now if i sue these queries :

```
db.testIndexes.find().sort({ratings:1}).pretty();
```

Result is like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584e6cbdd23d3b48f9cb819f"),
    "type" : "depart",
    "item" : "aaa",
    "ratings" : [
            10,
            6,
            1
    ]
}  
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584e6cb2d23d3b48f9cb819e"),
    "type" : "depart",
    "item" : "aaa",
    "ratings" : [
            2,
            3,
            4
    ]
}  
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584e6ca8d23d3b48f9cb819d"),
    "type" : "depart",
    "item" : "aaa",
    "ratings" : [
            5,
            8,
            9
    ]
}
```

and for query

```
db.testIndexes.find().sort({ratings:-1}).pretty();
```

Results are:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584e6cbdd23d3b48f9cb819f"),
    "type" : "depart",
    "item" : "aaa",
    "ratings" : [
            10,
            6,
            1
    ]
}  
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584e6ca8d23d3b48f9cb819d"),
    "type" : "depart",
    "item" : "aaa",
    "ratings" : [
            5,
            8,
            9
    ]
}  
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584e6cb2d23d3b48f9cb819e"),
    "type" : "depart",
    "item" : "aaa",
    "ratings" : [
            2,
            3,
            4
    ]
}
```

As results does not seems to follow and order so can anyone help how mongo is sorting these results.

Thanks
Virendra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it does seem like the results are not following any order but actually they are. In your first sort `{ratings:1}`, what's happening here is the results are ordered by the smallest element in ratings. Since these are your lists:

```
[ 10, 6, 1 ]   [ 2, 3, 4 ]   [ 5, 8, 9 ]
```

So the list  `[ 10, 6, 1 ]`  smallest element is `1`, the list `[ 2, 3, 4 ]` smallest element is `2` and the list `[ 5, 8, 9 ]` smallest element is `5`. So the results are ordered in that way.

When you sort by descending, the same order happens but by maximum element in ratings.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @guvmaor86 this helped